# Oracle BI Administration tool - cannot connect

Tags: oracle

I would like to create a new repository with OBI Admin Tool but I am stucked at login to DTB with this error:

> The connection has failed

```
Connection_Type: OCI 10g/11g
Data Source Name: ** this is the same as it is in TNSNAMES.ORA file **
User Name:
Password:
```

Example of TNSNAMES.ORA:

```
DWH_PRIMARY =
(DESCRIPTION =
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my.host.name)(PORT = 1234))
   (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = my.service.name))        
 )
```

Example of form:

```
Connection Type: OCI 10g/11g
Data Source Name: DWH_PRIMARY
User Name: MY_LOGINNAME
Password: ************
```

But I am still getting "*The connection has failed*".

I can't even see new records in log file **NQSAdminTool.log**.

I did everything they suggest in these 2 links:

- [OBIEE 11g - Connection has failed](https://community.oracle.com/message/9997832)
- [OBIEE 11g Administration Tool Connection has failed error](http://codeit.com.au/2013/01/06/obiee-administration-tool-connection-has-failed-error/)

Can you advice me on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does `tnsping DWH_PRIMARY` work? Have you created the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable?

Comment: yes ... but I already fixed it .. i was using the bad "Data Source Name" .. because I needed to use the whole connection string (one-liner) and not this short one but this one in following format 

`( DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my.host.name)(PORT = 1234)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = my.service.name) (UR = A) ) )`